# Set dot color of `text-overflow: ellipsis`

Tags: css

I have a `div` with a fixed width, which has a `div` with text inside. Parts of the text are in a `span` for coloring. The text `div` has all necessary styles for text-overflow with dots at the end (ellipsis), but the dots are not inheriting the `span`'s color, because their definition is on the `div`. When I put the definition on the `span`, it ignores its parent's width.

Test code:

```css
.container {
  width: 120px;
}

.text {
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.color {
  color: #b02b7c;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="text">Lorem <span class="color">ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</span>
  </div>
  <!-- works -->
  <div>Lorem <span class="text color">ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur</span>
  </div>
  <!-- doesn't work -->
</div>
```

Is there any clean CSS way to solve this problem? I'd like to stick with `text-overflow: ellipsis;`, because the other solutions for text truncation are a bit messy in my opinion.

Referrent source at https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp

Answer (score 49, accepted):

If I understand your issue correctly, this might work for you:

```css
.container {
    width:120px;
    background: lightgray;
}
.text {
    white-space: nowrap;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    overflow: hidden;
    color:#b02b7c;
}
.color {
    color: black;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="text"><span class="color">Lorem</span> ipsum dolor sit amet, consetetur
    </div><!-- works -->
</div>
```

**[Demo Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/badAdviceGuy/VG3bK/5/)**

If the ellipsis is taking the color of the div, then make the div the color you want the ellipsis to be, and use `.color` to set the initial text black.

Comment: thinking out of the box, nice

Comment: WOW.. this is quite difficult because you cannot know what the real color of that text will be... imagine `<div><span>some text <a>link</a> other text</span></div>`  If you set the `color` on `div` to be `purple`, then when the `<a>` is truncated, it will be `purple` instead of the expected `<a>` color. Do you have any ideas if there is a solution for this?