# How to change just the ellipses color..ie..the 3 dots in the end of the text

Tags: javascript, css

I have a column populated by a database field and I get it to just show the ellipses. The text is black.

How can I change just the color of the 3 dots to say yellow?

Comment: Please post some of your code.

Comment: Wrap the dots in a span and style the span?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Set dot color of \`text-overflow: ellipsis\`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861125/set-dot-color-of-text-overflow-ellipsis)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you may use an extra wrapper to switch text colors:

```css
p {
font-size:3em;/* demo */
  margin:1em;
  white-space:nowrap;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-overflow:ellipsis;
  width:8em;
  background:#222;
  color:yellow;
  font-weight:bold;
}
span {
  font-weight:normal;
  color:white;
}
```

```html
<p><span>some text to overflow</span></p>
```