# Styling a multi-line ellipsis (...)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to style the ellipsis (`...`) of a 3 line piece of text that, when clicked on, reveals the full amount of text using jQuery. Currently I've been able to create a multi-line ellipsis on 3 lines for webkit browsers, but it isn't compatible with all browsers like IE & Firefox but works on Chrome & Edge.

With the influence of [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21861125/set-dot-color-of-text-overflow-ellipsis/21861334#21861334), I can only style the ellipsis when on one line but not 3 lines of text, making sure it overrules the other CSS.

Does anyone know how to apply this styling but to an ellipsis on the 3rd line? My attempted code is below:

```js
$('.flex-text.description').click(function() {
  if ($(this).css('-webkit-line-clamp') == '3') {
    $(this).css('-webkit-line-clamp', 'initial');
  } else {
    $(this).css('-webkit-line-clamp', '3');
  }
});
```

```css
.sad-flex {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row wrap;
}

.flex-item {
  width: 23.5%;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

.flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) {
  margin-left: 2%
}

.flex-item:nth-of-type(n+5) {
  margin-top: 2%
}

.flex-item-image-link {
  width: 100%
}

.flex-item img {
  width: 100%;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
}

.flex-item,
.flex-text-content {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  font-size: 1em;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-family: arial;
  /* perhaps remove */
  justify-content: flex-start;
}

.flex-text-content {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item .flex-text.header {
  margin-bottom: 0;
  font-weight: 700;
  width: 100%;
}

.flex-item .flex-text.header a {
  color: #000
}

.flex-item .flex-text.price {
  padding-top: 20px;
  font-size: 1.4em;
  color: grey;
}

.flex-item .flex-text.description {
  font-size: 1em;
  padding-top: 20px;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  display: -webkit-box;
  -webkit-line-clamp: 3;
  -webkit-box-orient: vertical;
  /* Other ellipsis method: */
  /* max-height: 6em; */
  /* limits to 3 lines of text */
  /* ellipsis below: */
  /* white-space: nowrap; */
  /* text-overflow: ellipsis; */
  /* max-width: 650px; */
  /* solves the flex white-space nowrap width pushout problem */
  /* Limit to 3 lines, then ellipsis */
}

.flex-item .flex-btn {
  border: none;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 12px;
  color: #fff;
  background-color: #000;
  cursor: pointer;
  width: 100%;
  font-size: 1.3em;
  margin: auto auto 0 auto;
}

.flex-item .flex-btn:hover {
  opacity: 0.7
}

.flex-item ul {
  text-align: left
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
  .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(4n+1)) {
    margin-left: 3%
  }
  .flex-item {
    width: 48.5%
  }
  .flex-item:not(:nth-of-type(even)) {
    margin-left: 0
  }
  .flex-item:nth-of-type(n+3) {
    margin-top: 3%
  }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="sad-flex">
  <div class="flex-item">
    <a class="flex-item-image-link" href="#" data-galinkprocessed="true"><img src="https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/tp/3x2/" style="background-image:url(https://cml.sad.ukrd.com/image/219581.jpg)"></a>
    <div class="flex-text-content">
      <h2 class="flex-text header"><a href="#" data-galinkprocessed="true">Pine Cone</a></h2>
      <span class="flex-text price">$81.52</span>
      <span class="flex-text description">A delightful cone made of genuine North American pine, coated with sticky ooze for that authentic natural experience and some more text to just go here anyway  and some more text to just go here anyway and some more text to just go here anyway.</span>
    </div>
    <button onclick="location.href='#'" class="flex-btn">Add to Cart</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

I've made a codepen demo to demonstrate this: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRObXd

Comment: its working fine in the code snippet you've attached. What's your expectation?

Comment: but it doesn't style the ellipsis separately for a 3 line ellipsis

Comment: @Prajwal ... `but isn't compatible with all browsers like IE & firefox but works on Chrome & edge`

Comment: In summary: you need a cross-browser version of `-webkit-line-clamp` - see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18763551/clamping-lines-without-webkit-line-clamp

Comment: Well, CSS tricks suggests to go with clamp.js css-tricks https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/l/line-clamp/  github https://github.com/josephschmitt/Clamp.js

Comment: not sure if I have explained this clearly, but I'm not too fussed about the cross-browser compatibility problem, but more about the fact that I cannot style the ellipsis when it shows on 3 lines

Comment: That doesn't make much sense. Could you show an example of the states you want it to look like when it's open and closed.

Comment: If I'm not wrong you want to style three dots '...' which I believe is not possible unless you make it custom ellipses effect and then only you can style it

Comment: I essentially want this demo but on 3 lines: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/wRObXd - so a 3 line ellipsis but with the dots styled - I think my post was edited by someone which might have caused confusion here